# How can I give a style bold in android?

Tags: android, android-styles

How can I give bold and normal styles inside our styles.xml?
The code which I have given is:

```
<style name="textbold" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textstyle">bold</item>
</style>
<style name="textregular" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textstyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

But its showing error over here: `<item name="android:textstyle">`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's because it's `textStyle`, not `textstyle`. The attributes are case-sensitive.

```
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
```

Comment: search in internet or ask other question if you don't find it anywhere

Comment: if I've 
        `<item android:title="Request">
            <menu>
                <item> .... </item> 
            </menu>
        </item>` how do I make "Request" as bold